# How to import .sql file into MySQL using PowerShell script?

Tags: mysql, powershell

I'm trying to import a dump file (.sql file containing CREATE/DROP/INSERT commands) into a remote MySQL server from a windows environment. I've got this PowerShell script to do the job for me by using *"MySQL shell utility"* functionalities installed in my environment

```bsh
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Add-Type –Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.11\Assemblies\v4.5.2\MySql.Data.dll'
$Connection = [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection]@{ConnectionString='server=192.168.100.100;Encrypt=false;uid=myUser;pwd=myPass;database=myDB;'}
$Connection.Open()
$sql = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$sql.Connection = $Connection
$sql.CommandText = "SOURCE D:/MySQL_Dumps/myFile.sql"
$sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
$Reader.Close()
$Connection.Close()
```

I can connect to the server and execute basic `SELECT` queries, using `ExecuteNonQuery()`/`ExecuteScalar()`/`ExecuteReader()` methods, but receiving an error for this specific SOURCE command:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "You have an error
in your SQL syntax; check the manual  that corresponds to your MySQL server
version for the right syntax to use near 'SOURCE
D:/MySQL_Dumps/myFile.sql' at  line 1" At line:8 char:1
+ $sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MySqlException
```

I tried several alternatives to enter the path, like using double slashes or double backslashes but encountered the same error. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: `$sql.CommandText = Get-Content D:\MySQL_Dumps\myFile.sql -Raw`

Comment: Tested, didn't work!

Comment: Please elaborate. Do you get the same error? What is in the `D:\MySQL_Dumps\myFile.sql` file? Please, add this information *into the question* (especially if you get a different error now).

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same error; file contents are valid as it works perfectly on any IDE

Comment: It's not possible that replacing `"SOURCE D:/MySQL_Dumps/myFile.sql"` with the content of the SQL file would give you the same error, unless the file were sourcing itself. Which would be a problem in and out of itself.

Comment: replacing the content of the file makes the script working! which is not the case, as I don't have any other workaround to avoid referring the file

Comment: For what it is worth: according to the MySql documentation, queries should be followed by a **semicolon**: ["*A query normally consists of an SQL statement followed by a semicolon. (There are some exceptions where a semicolon may be omitted. QUIT, mentioned earlier, is one of them. We'll get to others later.)*"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/entering-queries.html). If you receive any error like this, I would start to be strict on the MySQL query syntax. Meaning: `$sql.CommandText = "SOURCE D:/MySQL_Dumps/myFile.sql;"`

Answer (score 22):

```
./mysql -u root -p DatabaseName -e "source C:\path\to\my_sql_file.sql"
```

Comment: This does the trick @mytuny. But can you explain what is happening after the `-e` flag or point me to an article please? Have been scratching my head while trying to understand that part.

Comment: For those who stumble upon this thread and need and explanation. The `-e` or `--execute` flags are used to execute an SQL statement. If you already in the MySQL shell or want to execute your statement from a file, you can use the MySQL command `source`.

[Execute Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute)
[Source Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html)

Comment: Excellent explanation @Murolack!!

Comment: Thanks for the "source" command, never saw that before. Why does the input pipe not work in PS: `./mysql -u root -p DatabaseName < file.sql` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql.CommandText = Get-Content D:\MySQL_Dumps\myFile.sql -Raw
```

This worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a little bit old, but it is the top one when searching about this issue on Google, so I'm going to put my pennies on the pot.

I ran into the same issue in a project, and after using the snippet

```
$sql.CommandText = Get-Content D:\MySQL_Dumps\myFile.sql -Raw
```

I got issues with scripts using custom **DELIMITER** characters (*.sql* files containing stored procedures, triggers and user defined functions).

After some research, I found that there is the class [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlScript](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlScript.htm) that handles *.sql* files/scripts execution. According with [this thread](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46429), from connector version 5.2.8 onward, custom DELIMITER problem does not exist anymore.
So, what worked for me was the following snippet:

```
$Script = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlScript($MySqlConn)
$Script.Query = Get-Content $ScriptPath -Raw
$Script.Execute() | Out-Null
```

I am currently using MySql.Data.dll version 8.0.25.